# Lifetime collision when bounding reference of a trait as IntoIterator

Tags: rust

I tried to implement some graph algorithms on generic graphs. For that, I defined two graph traits which would return either a generic trait (having set-operations) *SetGraph* or an IntoIterator used to iterate over the nodes *NeighborhoodIteratorGraph*.

```
pub trait NeighborhoodIteratorGraph<'a> {
    //which into_iterator do we have?
    type IntoIter: 'a + std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>;
    fn get_neighborhood_iterator(&'a self, index: usize) -> Self::IntoIter;
}

pub trait SetGraph<'a>
where
    &'a Self::S: IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
    Self::S: 'a,
{
    type S;
    fn get_neighborhood(&'a self, index: usize) -> &'a Self::S;
}
```

Because one is usually able to iterate over sets, I also implemented *NeighborhoodIteratorGraph* for all *SetGraph* which are able to iterate over their sets.

```
impl<'a, G> NeighborhoodIteratorGraph<'a> for G
where
    G: SetGraph<'a>,
    &'a G::S: IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
{
    type IntoIter = &'a G::S;
    fn get_neighborhood_iterator(&'a self, index: usize) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.get_neighborhood(index)
    }
}
```

I needed to add a lifetime to *NeighborrhoodIteratorGraph* otherwise the compiler would tell me my implementation would have an unbounded lifetime.

However I quicky run into problems with these lifetimes and I get an error for the following code:

```
struct Foo<'a, G: NeighborhoodIteratorGraph<'a>> {
    graph: G,
    //otherwise we get an error because 'a wouldn't be used
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a G>,
}

impl<'a, G: NeighborhoodIteratorGraph<'a>> Foo<'a, G> {
    pub fn find_matching_for<I>(&mut self, nodes: I) -> bool
    where
        I: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
    {
        for node in self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3) {}
        return true;
    }
}
```

> error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements

It seems that the PhantomData field is more a hack and I can't find a way in which I get a set refernce which can be seen as a IntoIterator object.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0aaf72b7ee2ad53bd39e4423f518e1e4) is the Rust Playground of the problem.

Full error message:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:38:32
   |
38 |         for node in self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3) {}
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 34:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:34:5
   |
34 | /     pub fn find_matching_for<I>(&mut self, nodes: I) -> bool
35 | |     where
36 | |         I: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
   | |_________________________________________________^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:38:21
   |
38 |         for node in self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3) {}
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 33:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:33:6
   |
33 | impl<'a, G: NeighborhoodIteratorGraph<'a>> Foo<'a, G> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:38:32
   |
38 |         for node in self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3) {}
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&'a G`
              found `&G`
```

Comment: Why does `get_neighborhood` require a `&'a self` with `'a` being an argument of the trait? The `for<'a>` syntax might be helpful here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html, https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds, https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6uobit/fora_lifetime_syntax/

Comment: Good question. To be honest I think I got careless and insertes too many `'a`. However, deleting `'a` from the argument and return of `get_neighborhood` doesn't change the error.
The HRTB syntax seems to get me almost there, but the type `IntoIter` of the implementation still results in errors, because there are no HRTB for associated types (at least I couldn't find an example). The updated playground: (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7379720b0321437e5ff66b70bcf939f3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a workaround for the lack of generic associated types, which are currently very unstable. Something Like

```rust
pub trait NeighborhoodIteratorGraph {
    type IntoIter<'a>: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize> + 'a;
    fn get_neighborhood_iterator<'b>(&'b self, index: usize) -> Self::IntoIter<'b>;
}
```

would serve you perfectly if they were stable.

The first thing I did is remove the lifetime bound on `NeighborhoodIteratorGraph` and add it to the return type:

```rust
pub trait NeighborhoodIteratorGraph {
    type IntoIter: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>;
    fn get_neighborhood_iterator<'b>(&'b self, index: usize) -> Self::IntoIter
    where
        Self::IntoIter: 'b;
}
```

I then removed unnecessary lifetime annotations from `SetGraph`:

```rust
pub trait SetGraph<'a>
where
    &'a Self::S: IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
    Self::S: 'a,
{
    type S;
    fn get_neighborhood(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::S;
}
```

I then changed the blanket impl's signature to match the modified traits, and changed the impl from `G` to `&'a G` to properly constrain the lifetime `'a`:

```
impl<'a, G> NeighborhoodIteratorGraph for &'a G
where
    G: SetGraph<'a>,
    &'a G::S: IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
{
    type IntoIter = &'a G::S;
    fn get_neighborhood_iterator<'b>(&'b self, index: usize) -> Self::IntoIter
    where
        Self::IntoIter: 'b,
    {
        self.get_neighborhood(index)
    }
}
```

Because of those changes I was able to simplify `Foo` and its impl:

```rust
struct Foo<G: NeighborhoodIteratorGraph> {
    graph: G,
}

impl<G: NeighborhoodIteratorGraph> Foo<G> {
    pub fn find_matching_for<I>(&mut self, nodes: I) -> bool
    where
        I: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
    {
        for node in self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3) {}
        return true;
    }
}
```

Leaving the compiler output with nothing but dead code warnings. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=pub%20trait%20NeighborhoodIteratorGraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20IntoIter%3A%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3AIntoIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20usize%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_neighborhood_iterator%3C%27b%3E(%26%27b%20self%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AIntoIter%0A%20%20%20%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%3A%3AIntoIter%3A%20%27b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20trait%20SetGraph%3C%27a%3E%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20Self%3A%3AS%3A%20IntoIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20usize%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Self%3A%3AS%3A%20%27a%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20S%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_neighborhood(%26self%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20%26Self%3A%3AS%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%2C%20G%3E%20NeighborhoodIteratorGraph%20for%20%26%27a%20G%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20G%3A%20SetGraph%3C%27a%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%26%27a%20G%3A%3AS%3A%20IntoIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20usize%3E%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20IntoIter%20%3D%20%26%27a%20G%3A%3AS%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_neighborhood_iterator%3C%27b%3E(%26%27b%20self%2C%20index%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20Self%3A%3AIntoIter%0A%20%20%20%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%3A%3AIntoIter%3A%20%27b%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.get_neighborhood(index)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Foo%3CG%3A%20NeighborhoodIteratorGraph%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20graph%3A%20G%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CG%3A%20NeighborhoodIteratorGraph%3E%20Foo%3CG%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20find_matching_for%3CI%3E(%26mut%20self%2C%20nodes%3A%20I)%20-%3E%20bool%0A%20%20%20%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20I%3A%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3AIntoIterator%3CItem%20%3D%20usize%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20node%20in%20self.graph.get_neighborhood_iterator(3)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)